# Need an LCD monitor that produces same picture as laptops and Apple screens

Tags: monitors

I've noticed Apple screens (desktop and ipads) and recent laptops (including non Apple) produce better picture than any LCD monitors I can find. What kind of monitors should I look for that have same picture quality?

Comment: Apple has great QC and out of the box calibration, but there are many other high end monitors that produce an equally good picture. Apple doesn't manufacture their own panels, nor do they use one single panel for every display. There's just no way to pick a monitor or even sets of monitors that are "as good as Apple" without at the very least picking a single reference monitor. I'd recommend that you instead give a budget, target resolution and size, and anything else you'd like, and we can work a recommendation from there. You'll probably want a monitor with IPS, but beyond that, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: I've got a 14 inch laptop with 1920 x 1080 and a 24 inch monitor with 1920 x 1200, the 24 inch isn't as sharp as the laptop but I'm not sure that is what the issue is, the colour on the laptop looks much better especially for web pages. However movies look very similar if not better on the 24 inch but I don't really care about the movies, its the web pages and windows UI that is the problem. I've never had this issue with an apple screen. The monitor is Dell U2410F one of the older models and it has IPS.

Comment: Is the U2410F suiting you? Also still going to need budget, target resolution and size, and anything else you'd like. It's also quite possible that your monitor simply isn't calibrated correctly. Have you tried switching viewing modes, downloading an online color profile, or calibrating by eye/with a meter?

Comment: I changed the preset mode from standard to sRGB and it looks much better now, I still need a new monitor eventually though. I was thinking of budgeting at about $600 AUD for a 24 inch 4k monitor, would anything around that price be worthwhile?

Comment: Bit of a strange question, should be my last one. Do you game at all? If so, what GPU do you have? Do you have any plans to change that in the near future?

Comment: I do game but not new games, its only for a laptop its an onboard GPU. Even if I do get a PC in future I'm not that fussed about gaming performance.

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR: the [Dell P2415Q](https://au.pcpartpicker.com/product/4TWrxr/dell-monitor-p2415q)

Given the target of a 24" 4K monitor, we're basically left with two options: the LG 24UD58-B and the Dell P2415Q.

Both use the same IPS panel manufactured by LG; the differences are in out-of-the-box calibration (Dell has a better reputation and provides statistics in the box for each monitor), connectivity (the 24UD58-B has 1x DisplayPort and 2x HDMI while the P2415Q has 3x DisplayPort, 1x HDMI, and 1x Mini DisplayPort), and Freesync (only the 24UD58-B has Freesync.)

Because you don't game on an AMD card at the moment, and live in Australia where availability of the 24UD58-B is quite poor (I couldn't find any listings at the moment), this leaves the P2415Q, which just squeaks in under the budget at $585 AUD.

[Here's a full review of the monitor](https://pcmonitors.info/reviews/dell-p2415q/). Pros are excellent calibration, good contrast (for an LCD), good pixel response times, and of course, 4K. Weaknesses were confined to a too-narrow color space and a heavily matte finish.

Comment: I found an LG https://www.jbhifi.com.au/computers-tablets/monitors/lg/lg-27ud58-27-uhd-ips-freesync-monitor/314277/ how does this one compare to these 24 inch monitors?

Comment: @el_pup_le Quite well if you'd like a 27" monitor.

Comment: is there any loss in picture quality from the bigger screen size?

Comment: @el_pup_le Lower pixel density of course, but besides that, no.

Comment: Cool I'll probably go with the p2715q